# Test method without using real Internet

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I am trying to test a method that makes a verification of internet connection via a method called `isOnline(context: Context)`. But the thing is that when I do so it makes a real internet verification and prompts an error. I even forced to Mockito to return the value from the `isOnline(context: Context)` by using `Mockito.`when`(sut.isOnline(context)).thenReturn(true)` but still does not works, how can I solve this, I have serched a lot without success. Here my code

Method that I want to test

```
fun getAllCharacters() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _getAllCharactersResponseLiveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val charactersList = getCharactersFromDataBaseUseCase.getAllCharactersFromDataBase()

        if (isOnline(context) && charactersList.isEmpty()) {
            _getAllCharactersResponseLiveData.postValue(getAllCharactersUseCase.getAllCharacters())
        } else if (!isOnline(context) && charactersList.isNotEmpty() ||
            isOnline(context) && charactersList.isNotEmpty()
        ) {
            _getAllCharactersResponseLiveData.postValue(
                Resource.Success(
                    getCharactersFromDataBaseUseCase.getAllCharactersFromDataBase()
                )
            )
        } else {
            _getAllCharactersResponseLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error())
        }
    }

    fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

How I am testing it

```
@Test
fun internet_connected_and_empty_data_base_gets_info_from_api_success() {
    //given

    //when
    Mockito.`when`(sut.isOnline(context)).thenReturn(true)
    sut.getAllCharacters()
    val expected = sut.getAllCharactersLiveData.getOrAwaitValue().data
    //then
    assertThat(expected?.first()?.name).isEqualTo("char1")
}
```

Comment: Have your `sut` extend your actual class/implementation under test and overwite `isOnline` to always return `true`.  You don't need a mock for this.

Comment: Could you explain better please? I am kind of new to unit testing and I am not quite aware of what you meant :(

Comment: Sure, but show me where you initialize `sut`.